# If i cancel Apple Music subscription, and then resubscribe almost immediately, will my previously downloaded music still be there?

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-id, apple-music

I need to change from another country's App Store to the US App Store as I have relocated. Some apps, like Venmo, are only available in the US App Store. So to download them, I need to change to the US App Store. But to do so, I have to unsubscribe from Apple Music.

My intention is to resubscribe to Apple Music as soon as I am on the US App Store.

My question is: would my downloaded music from Apple Music (not previously purchased) still be there when I resubscribe?

I'd rather not the hassle of having to search and download all the tracks i previously downloaded when i resubscribe.

Is this documented or explained by Apple or someone’s personal experience?

Comment: Similar but not exact same scenario are [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244692/) and [there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297209/)

Answer (score -1):

Google venmo for the App Store to change it if you go via browser you won't have to cancel subscription ; now to go back if you don't intend on staying in us App Store you'd have to find an app only available in whatever country/region your needing to go back too hope that helps